Extracting Arguments from Function Calls with Regular Expression
Problem Formulation
I have to extract arguments from function calls with NodeJS.
For example:
`foo0()` => [""]
`foo1(1)` => ["1"]
`foo2(1, "HelloThere")` => ["1", "\"HelloThere\""]
`foo3(foo1(1), foo2(foo1(1), 2), 3)` => ["foo(1)", "foo2(foo1(1), 2)", 3]
`foo4(
 // 123456
 foo1(1),
 abcdef,
 foo2(1, 2) + foo3(1+2, 333, "Hello"),
 "\nRandom,((,,,Dummy )),, ,, ,String\n"
)` => ["// 123456\n foo1(1)", "abcdef", "foo2(1, 2) + foo3(1+2, 333, \"Hello\")", "\"\nRandom,((,,,Dummy )),, ,, ,String\n\"\n"]

Attempts
First I have starts with a naive attempt:
>> `foo2(1, "HelloThere")`.split(/\s?,\s/g)
Array [ "foo2(1", '"HelloThere")' ]

then just take foo2( and ) beforehand.
But obviously it would not work on more complicated cases:
>> `foo3(foo1(1), foo2(foo1(1), 2), 3)`
Array(4) [ "foo3(foo1(1)", "foo2(foo1(1)", "2)", "3)" ]

After some researches, I found a way to match balanced parentheses
But I am not sure how to use it to separate arguments.
Many thanks for the help.
Edit1: Parser
I wrote a very simple parser to parse arguments:
// t is input, foo*( and ) is stripped beforehand.
let 
    p0 = 0, p1 = 0, i = 0;
    pts = 0,    // parentheses
    brs = 0,    // brackets
    qt0 = 0,    // quotes `
    qt1 = 0,    // quotes '
    qt2 = 0     // quotes "
;
for (const c of t) {
    switch (c) {
    // Edit: Estus Flask's comment.
    case "(": if (!qt0 && !qt1 && !qt2) { pts++; } break;
    case ")": if (!qt0 && !qt1 && !qt2) { pts--; } break;
    case "[": if (!qt0 && !qt1 && !qt2) { brs++; } break;
    case "]": if (!qt0 && !qt1 && !qt2) { brs--; } break;
    case "`": qt0 = !qt0; break;
    case "'": qt1 = !qt1; break;
    case "\"": qt2 = !qt2; break;
    case ",":
        if (!pts && !brs && !qt0 && !qt1 && !qt2) {
            //
            // t.slice(p0, p1) is an argument, do stuffs.
            //
            p0 = ++p1;
            continue;
        }
    }
    p1++;
}

This seems satisfy my requirement so far.
Therefore, problem could be reduced to matching all , that is not quoted by any (), [], ``, '', "" pairs within a string.
Even though I have a parser now, I am still wondering if the problem could be resolved with regular expressions.
Please let me now if you have any idea on this, thank you.

This sounds a bit complex. The nested parentheses, nested function calls, additional input that could be used (e.g. an object), commas and parentheses in strings and all that, etc. If it allows, you should look into a basic JavaScript parser.

@code Yes if this is not possible with regular expressions, then I would go instead with a parser. Just want to figure out if there are any possible way to do this with builtin regex before I start working on a js parser.

You may use regex in a parser, but a naive approach leads nowhere. If you're doing this for a specific purpose and not as an exercise, there are already existing js parsers out there

@EstusFlask Sorry for the late reply. I have write a simple argument parser with common js, please see the updated question, thanks.

@imakak So the goal is to write a parser and not just solve this with a third-party lib? Use parenthesis balancing as you suggested. It shouldn't be limited to regex as JS regexes don't support this, as explained in the linked question. You can use any solution for bracket/braces/parentheses matching/balancing (use these keywords) from SO or GH. There will still be a problem because a parser that doesn't understand JS syntax will inevitably have edge cases, e.g. ":)" argument or as you said, "problem could be reduced to matching all ,". Use Acorn or other real JS parser to make it practical

Also, the problem with your matching algorhithm is that it doesn't think in groups. It should work recursively and return a hierarchy of ", (, etc matched groups, with some understanding of quote escaping (this is what full-featured JS parser would do). Then you can process them and figure out if a comma is arg delimiter or a part of a string. I don't remember a specific third-party lib I used for matching like this one, but this would be a requirement for it

@EstusFlask Yes. Actually, I am working a c preprocessor-like that processes tool that process common js modules; As you said, it doesn't handle such edge cases properly, thanks you for noticing that.

Is the input representing JavaScript language snippets? Like with all the possibilities of inline comments, comment blocks, multiline, template strings having inline code, regex literals, ...etc?

In general, regular expressions can't easily deal with nestable patterns. And it gets even harder when you need to deal with the delimiters being escaped or quoted.

@trincot Yes the input could be any valid common js function calls.

Then don't reinvent the wheel: what you have is only scratching the surface. Instead use a library that builds an AST for you, like esprima.

@trincot Okay, thank you.

@Barmar Well this doesn't seem possible only with regular expressions, according to the discussion. Thank you for replying.
